# shuffle order of items in a list based on groupby

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of object. Each of them has a distance property.
I want to shuffle the order of items in each group.
For ex: 
if 10 elements has distance=0, and 20 elements has distance=5, I have to shuffle the elements with distance=0 and then shuffle elements with distance=5.
It should not shuffle distance=0 with distance=5 of what so ever.

i have been trying with few things with Random and groupby, but didn't give me proper result.

Can anyone show me some light??

Comment: the result should be a new List or do you want to shuffle inside the existing one? can you show your code?

Comment: I have to shuffle the list every time users see the page. so I guess a new list .

Comment: Are the items already in distance order? I have the strangest sense of deja vu...

Comment: yes they are sorted based on distance already.

Comment: How about, rather than making us play 20 questions, you show us a concrete example with a small list. Show us the initial list and how you want it modified. Because what you've given us so far is somewhat ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a method to shuffle a sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Random random)
{
    var list = source.ToList();
    for (int i = list.Count; i > 0; i--)
    {
        var index = random.Next(i);
        var temp = list[index];
        list[index] = list[i - 1];
        list[i - 1] = temp;
        yield return temp;
    }
}
```

You just group the items, and project each group to the shuffled version of that group:

```
var random = new Random();
var query = data.GroupBy(item => item.Distance)
    .SelectMany(group => group.Shuffle(random));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample `Item` class:

```
public class Item
{
    private static int index = 0;   // for test purposes

    public int Distance { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }

    public Item(int distance)
    {
        this.Distance = distance;
        this.Data = ++index;
    }
}
```

Code:

```
List<Item> list= new List<Item>
{
    new Item(10),
    new Item(10),
    new Item(10),
    new Item(10),
    new Item(10),
    new Item(20),
    new Item(20),
    new Item(20),
};

Random rnd = new Random();
foreach (var group in from e in list
                      orderby rnd.NextDouble()
                      group e by e.Distance into g
                      orderby g.Key
                      select g)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group with distance {0}", group.Key);
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Item Distance={0}, Data={1}", item.Distance, item.Data);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("----");
}
```

Result:

```
Group with distance 10
Item Distance=10, Data=3
Item Distance=10, Data=1
Item Distance=10, Data=2
Item Distance=10, Data=5
Item Distance=10, Data=4
----
Group with distance 20
Item Distance=20, Data=7
Item Distance=20, Data=6
Item Distance=20, Data=8
----
```

Answer (score 1):

let's say this is your class

```
public class Element
{
    public int Distance { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and you have those elements in it

```
List<Element> myList = new List<Element>();
myList.Add(new Element() { Distance = 10, Name = "test1" });
myList.Add(new Element() { Distance = 10, Name = "test2" });
myList.Add(new Element() { Distance = 20, Name = "test3" });
myList.Add(new Element() { Distance = 20, Name = "test4" });
```

then this groups your elements by distance and shuffles the lists, which contain the elements

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var Result = myList.GroupBy(r => r.Distance)
    .Select(x => new[] {
        new {
        Group =  x.Key, 
        Items =  x.Select(r => r.Name).OrderBy(_ => rnd.Next())
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

possible to simplify @Servy example:

```
var query = data.GroupBy(item => item.Distance)
    .SelectMany(group => group.OrderBy(Guid.NewGuid()));
```

Comment: `Guid.NewGuid()` is expensive operation with string type, use `Random` instead

Comment: Guids are not random, they're unique.  Ordering on a guid does not necessarily shuffle the items in the list, as they won't necessarily be in a random order.